# Последовательность команд Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Может кто объяснить почему в первой части при выполнении кода отсчет начиниается с  1, ведь начальное значение `x=0`, а во второй части с `1`

И 2 вопрос: Как работает выполнение кода во 2 случае? Ведь я не вывожу ничего, как интерпретатор понимает, что нужно выполнить этот код `x += 1`, там же нет команды `print`

`1 случай`

```
x = 0
while x < 5:
    x += 1
    print(f'The current value of x is {x}')
```

`2 случай`

```
x = 0
while x < 5:
    print(f'The current value of x is {x}')
    x += 1
```

Заранее спасибо и извините за столько легкие вопросы, только начинаю свою путь. Спасибо

Comment: Потому что, очевидно, в первой части вы выполняете печать после сложения, а во второй перед сложением

Comment: «как интерпретатор понимает, что нужно выполнить этот код» — очень просто, последовательно выполняет команды в коде и всё. У вас после строчки с print'ом идёт строчка с `x += 1` и нет абсолютно никакой причины, почему интерпретатор должен не выполнять эту строчку, а значит он её выполнит

Comment: @andreymal, я к тому, что я же не вывожу ничего, как он сам выводит в консоль?

Comment: Вы же написали print, поэтому и выводит. Уберите print — тогда не будет выводить

Comment: @andreymal, я его написал для `f'The current value of x is {x}'`, но не для `x+=1`, поэтому не понимаю как это работает

Comment: Так строка `x+=1` ничего никогда и не выводит. То, что вы для принта написали — то и выводится

Comment: @andreymal, выводит же, если ее убрать то просто остается `The current value of x is 0`, а когда ставишь ее, то получается `The current value of x is 1`, потом `The current value of x is 2` и тд

Comment: Нет, без принта ничего не остаётся, вы меня обманываете. Я запускаю ваш код без принта, и не выводится абсолютно ничего https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWeDe.png

Comment: Если же сделать наоборот — убрать x+=1 и оставить только print, то получится вечный цикл, потому что значение x никто не меняет, оно остаётся всегда равно 0 и условие цикла `x < 5` всегда выполняется, и принт всегда выводит этот самый 0 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dWV1.png

Comment: И из этих двух примеров наглядно видно, что строка `x+=1` ничего никогда не выводит, выводом занимается только print

Comment: @andreymal, посмотите пожалуйста 2 вариант. Его скопируйте. Единственное, что я не понимаю, почему без слова `print`  на 4 строке он все равно делает увеличение на 1, то есть это срабатывает и выводится еще почему-то? `x+=1` как это работает?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он не должен делать увеличение на 1? Наличие или отсутствие принта где-либо абсолютно никак не влияет на весь остальной код.

Comment: «x+=1 как это работает?» — очень просто: берёт значение переменной x, увеличивает его на единицу и сохраняет результат обратно в ту же самую переменную x

Comment: @andreymal, я так решил, потому что код сверху вниз проверяется интерепретатором, и как он может выводить то, что было определено до принта? Я все равно не понимаю этот момент. Согласно синтаксису, нужно написать сам слово `print`, а тут без него почему-то вывелось

Comment: Повторяю третий раз: без принта ничего нигде никогда не выводится. Повторяю ещё раз: если вы уберёте все принты в своём коде, то никакого вывода не будет. Я вам уже показывал пример без принтов выше https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWeDe.png

Comment: В конце концов, можно взять отладчик, «прошагать» программу по строкам и увидеть, что вывод появляется только после того, как выполняется строка с принтом, а после выполнения строки `x += 1` никакого вывода не происходит https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bLhb.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 случай

```
x = 0 # Старт это 0
while x < 5:
    x += 1 # x + 1 = 1
    print(f'The current value of x is {x}') # Выводим то что в x ( в прошлой строке мы изменили значение в x с 0 на 1)
```

Выведет 1..2...etc

2 случай

```
x = 0 # изначально у нас 0
while x < 5:
    print(f'The current value of x is {x}') # выводим значение переменной x = 0 
    x += 1 # К x добавили 1, теперь x = 1
```

вывод такой 0..1...etc